# Initializing 'ABMultiValueRef *' (aka 'const void **') with an expression of type 'CFTypeRef'

Tags: ios6, automatic-ref-counting, abaddressbook

I get following warning under ARC:

```
Initializing 'ABMultiValueRef *' (aka 'const void **') with an expression of type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') discards qualifiers.
```

on line

```
ABMultiValueRef *phones = ABRecordCopyValue(abPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

`abPerson` is of `ABRecordRef` type.

What's wrong with this code?

P.S. I checked and everything works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ABRecordCopyValue` returns everything as a `CFTypeRef`. You must cast values to the particular reference type you want.